# How does the communication between app, proxy and google work?

Tags: android, google-api, server, google-cloud-messaging

I'm currently developing an android application with two versions prod and dev. Everything is working fine, however I don't understand what is actually happening in the background. I have created a diagram to illustrate my setup.

My communication setup (app->server->google):

[image]

Both versions have the same GCM sender (created in the same google project) and different google api keys (each app has its own applicationID). A server is responsible for the communication between the users of each app version. An app sends the server the user's regID and message. The server then forwards this request and the google api key 1 of prod to google. Google then sends the corresponding push notifications.

This setup is working for both app versions prod and dev. I tried to switch the google api key (1/prod) of the server to the other one (2/dev) in case the dev app is communicating with the server. As a result no messages could be sent anymore.

Can somebody help me understand what is actually happening?

My theory is that google registers the regIDs with the initially sent google api key.